# Is there a standard symbol for a multiset version of the natural numbers

Tags: notation, multisets

In other words, is there a standard symbol for the multiset $N$ where:

$$N = \mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N} \cup \mathbb{N} \cup \ldots$$

Or better yet, is there another, more concise way to represent what $N$ is?

**Edit:**

I realize where I was going wrong. I was thinking of $\cup$ as an addition-like  operator (it was late last night). I meant to define $N$ as:

$$N = \{\{1, 1, 1, \ldots, 2, 2, 2, \ldots, 3, 3, 3, \dots, \cdots\}\}$$

**Edit 2:**

$$N = \mathbb{N} + \mathbb{N} + \mathbb{N} + \ldots$$

**Edit 3:**

Here's the context I'm using it in:

> Let $D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_n$ each be subsets of the multiset $N$ where $N$ is ...

As an example, $D_1$ could be $\{\{1,1,2,4,4,5\}\}$ but not $\{\{\ \frac{1}{2}, \pi, \pi, e^7\}\}$. After that, I'll never mention $N$ again (as far as I know). If there isn't a simple way to represent $N$, is it concise and clear enough to say that "every element of $D_i$ is in $\mathbb{N}$, for all $i$"?

Comment: What does $\cup$ mean here exactly?

Comment: The union of two sets.

Comment: But the union of two sets is a set, not a multiset. And  if $\cup$ is set union then $\Bbb N\cup\Bbb N\cup\cdots$ is equal to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: I am afraid your edit does not really clarify your question. First of all, your formal definition of $N$ just gives $N = \mathbb{N}$. Nevertheless, I suppose your idea is to define some multiset, but in this case you should clearly define what you mean by "..." (there are four occurrences of "...")

Comment: $N$ is a supposed to be a multiset with an infinite number of *all* the natural numbers (not just 1, 2, and 3). Hence, the fourth ellipsis.

Comment: Do you mean the set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ of infinite sequences of natural numbers?

Comment: The term "infinite number" is not precise enough.

Comment: No dxiv, I don't think so.

Comment: If your context makes it clear that + denotes multiset union and your formulation of multisets already allows $\omega$-many copies of a given element, then you could probably just denote it $\sum_i^{\infty} \mathbb{N}$. That said it's probably best to use whatever language your formulation of multisets does to specify it. E.g. $N = (\mathbb{N}, m)$, where $m$ is a mapping from the underlying set to ordinals, and $m(n) = \omega$.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\{\{1,1,2,4,4,5\}\}$? It is not a set, since it has repeated elements. Is it an ordered [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple), or a possibly infinite sequence, or ...?

Comment: Is that not the notation for a multiset?

Comment: Netiher [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) nor [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiset.html) use $\{\{\cdots\}\}$ for multisets.

Comment: I've read that you could use $\{\{\cdots\}\}$ to distinguish between sets and multisets. I haven't been able to find it just now so I might be wrong.

Comment: Is there answer to the last question yes or no? If yes then we're done, if no then what is another way to say it concisely at the end of a sentence.

Comment: I have seen the double set brackets for multisets. Also, at least from the "context" you are trying to use it, can you just skip defining this $N$ object and say that each $D_i$ is a multiset of natural numbers? This seems to remove a lot of this headache while being very clear(in my opinion) as to what you would be talking about.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that in many formulations, multisets do not allow for infinite instances of the same element, so depending on how exactly a multiset is defined, $N$ may not be one.(For example a common definition of multiset is an ordered pair (A,f) Where A is a set and f is a function from A to $\mathbb{N}$. Since $\infty\not\in\mathbb{N}$, it isn't possible to have infinitely many instances of any element in a multiset under this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my question, the context I'm using $N$ in does not actually depend on a multiset "version" of the natural numbers. It suffices to say that "$D_i$ is a multiset of natural numbers" for all $i$, thanks to Sean English.

To answer to original question. No, there is no standard "symbol" for a multiset version of natural numbers.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in my statements or questions. I read an introduction to combinatorics which briefly mentioned multisets without giving a formal definition of them. So, I thought what I was saying should make sense. I realized that I was wrong with the help of G. H. Faust, dxiv, and others.

Answer (score 1):

First, I guess you mean that $N$ is the disjoint union of "some" copies of $\mathbb{N}$. If "some" is an integer $k$, you could represent $N$ as the set
$$
  N = \{(i, j) \mid 1 \leqslant i \leqslant k, j \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
More generally, a disjoint union of a family of sets $(S_i)_{i \in I}$, where each $S_i$ is equal to $\mathbb{N}$, can be represented by the set
$$
  N = \{(i, j) \mid i \in I, j \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
In this representation, $S_i =  \{(i, j) \mid j \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{i\} \times \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Not quite. Look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You mean just a function $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$? For example $f(5)$ would be the number of copies of $5$ that $f$ has. Or have the range be $\{0\} \cup \mathbb N$. Of course $f \subset \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ as a relation, additionally with the function property.

Your first edit: Since $\{a,a\} = a$ always, you just have $N = \{\mathbb N\}$, i.e. $N$ is the set with one element $a$, and $a$ is the set with elements $1,2,3,\ldots$.

Your second edit: $N = \emptyset$ because there is no natural number that can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ where each $a_i \in \mathbb N$.

Your third edit: $D_1 = \{\{1,2,4,5\}\}$. Of course $|D_1| = 1$ and the size of the only element of $D_1$ is $4$.

Comment: Would it be valid to say something similar to: $S \subset f$ where $S = \{\{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3\}\}$ and $f(1) = f(2) = f(3) = \ldots = \infty$?

Comment: @NoahMay you can't have it both ways. If you want to use standard mathematical notation then $\{a,a\} = \{a\}$, always. If you want to invent some random new notation then you have one of two choices: either you can make a new set theory that can serve as the foundation of most of mathematics, or you can find a construction in the usual set theory and notation that represents your notation. Of course, in this case, your notation should *not* conflict with existing, widely used notation. Which is what you keep doing when you write the same number twice and expect it to have a different meaning.